# Mod_rewrite return 404 error

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu). Site directory:

```
.htaccess
index.php
catalog.php
```

When I type in browser:

```
site.local/about-company - redirect to index.php
site.local/faq - redirect to index.php
site.local/catalog - return 404

**.htaccess**
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Comment: What are you expecting when user enter `catalog`?

Comment: I expect redirect to index.php

Comment: Try appending flags in your rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R=302,L]`

Comment: no change with RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ index.php [R=302,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 have only Apache/2.4.7
This version Apache with bug in mod_rewrite module.
Now on http://apache.org actually version is 2.4.9. Use this or wait 2.4.9 in Ubuntu Server.